# How to cleanup tomcat server logfiles with crontab (permissions restricted)

Tags: server, permissions, cron

I have a `tomcat` server that generates access logfiles on a daily rotation.

To clean them up every X days, I tried configuring the following `crontab -e`:

```
@weekly find /var/log/tomcat8/localhost_access_log.*.txt -mtime +10 -delete
```

Problem: I'm getting a `Permission denied` error running this. Because the `/var/log/tomcat8` folder has `tomcat:tomcat` user:group permissions, and I'm logged in as a different one.

So, how could I best create a cronjob that has permissions to delete those files?

Or should I just add the crontab via `sudo crontab -e`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to run `crontab` which can access files owned by user `tomcat` you can execute the command as user `tomcat`

Run `crontab` as user `tomcat` using:

```
sudo crontab -u tomcat -e
```

Comment: crontab -u is only available for root, hence `sudo crontab -u tomcat -e`

Comment: What if someone want to maintain the cronjobs who does not know about a job configured with `tomcat` user explicit. Is it possible for them to detect the job?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134906/how-do-i-list-all-cron-jobs-for-all-users) you can find how to do it. Note that: Under Ubuntu you can view crontab by `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/` and then a file for each user is in there.

Answer (score 1):

You could fix that using `sudo crontab -e`, since `root` will have sufficient permissions.

But `logrotate` seems to be the tool to rotate logs (and is most likely already in use in your system).

Have a look in `/etc/logrotate.d/` and try to find if `tomcat` already uses it.

Comment: well, but `logrotate` would not delete the files. Or would it? There is no logrotate for `localhost_access_log`, but I as well could create one that does not rotate, but just delete the files after x days, if possible?

Comment: `logrotate` can be configured to keep a defined number of files. With a correct frequency, it could match your "older than 10 days" test.

Comment: And logrotate automatically has the permissions to remove those files?

Comment: I don't use `tomcat`, so I can only guess, but most services use `logrotate` (see the content of `/etc/logrotate.d/` on your system), so `tomcat` is perhaps already using it.